# Assign JSON data to Knockout view model in Coffee script

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript, asp.net-mvc-4

My view

```
<ul class="AvailableAdvertisers" data-bind="foreach: availableAdvertisers">
   <li class="advertiser" data-bind="selectedToggle: selected() == true, click: toggleSelected">
      <span class="name" data-bind="text: name"></span>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Coffe Script

```
class wizardPageModel
    constructor: (@jsonObject) ->
        @availableAdvertisers = @jsonObject.SelectedAdvertisers

        @selectedAdvertisers = ko.observableArray()
```

What I want to do is to initialize the view model with the JSON string I get on view load.

```
var testModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Tried to do applyBindings after I include the javascript that contains my coffee script class definitions.

```
<script src="/Scripts/Wizard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myJson = @testModel;
    ko.applyBindings(new wizardPageModel(myJson));
    });
</script>
```

During debug I see that the JSON string is fine and I can see values in watch window.
Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Edit:
The $(document).ready(function(){ was throwing an exception

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tried replacing it with

> jQuery(function () {

that did not work either. So I did

```
<script src="/Scripts/Wizard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myJson = @testModel;
 ko.applyBindings(new wizardPageModel(myJson)); 
</script>
```

And now it gives me exception

> wizardPageModel is undefined.

Comment: what is nature of 'ko' object? Plase provide this source code (in gist maybe)

Comment: @CodeGroover, what do you mean? From the Knockout.js tutorials I never got the idea that I need to define them anywhere. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

What engine do you use to compile CoffeeScript? Seems that your `wizardPageModel` is being put into `(function() {})()`. If you use Mindscape Web Workbench then it is. Move to `Mindscape/Web Workbench Settings`, find your `.coffee` and check `Emit bare JavaScript`.
If you use console tool to compile then review the appropriate parameters for this.

---

The common way to detect such issues is to place breakpoints both to `wizardPageModel` definition and using `ko.applyBindings(new wizardPageModel(myJson));`. Then you'll be able to determine what is been called first and figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'd to give up on CoffeeScript and I wrote the JavaScript myself instead of CS producing it.